# Error with iconUrl for chrome.notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

So i'm switching from creating notifications from my in-page javascript to creating the notifications through the background script of my chrome extension. When I was creating the notifications in-page, I could just pass the image URL to the notification and everything would work fine. But i'm getting an error when I do this using chrome.notifications.

```
var icon_url = request.image;
console.log(icon_url);
chrome.notifications.create(
    {
        type:"image",
        iconUrl: icon_url,
        title: request.name,
        message: ("by "+request.artist+"\non "+request.album),
        eventTime: Number(pref[0])*1000
    },
    function(notificationId) {

    }
);
```

And when that runs, I get the following console error- `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running notifications.create: Image resource provided for notification type != image`

I'm dealing with image resources similar to [this link](http://mediaserver-cont-sv5-1-v4v6.pandora.com/images/public/amz/3/9/4/0/800070493_500W_500H.jpg). I suspect that it might be that I need to somehow load the image before using it (?). Thats the only problem I could think of because the image is already loaded on the Pandora page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt really answer my original question, but by changing the `type` of the notification from "image" to "basic" it worked as I expected it to work-

```
var icon_url = request.image;
console.log(icon_url);
chrome.notifications.create(
    {
        type:"basic",
        iconUrl: icon_url,
        title: request.name,
        message: ("by "+request.artist+"\non "+request.album),
        eventTime: Number(pref[0])*1000
    },
    function(notificationId) {

    }
);
```